# python, tailer and logrotate

Tags: python

I use [tailer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tailer/0.2.1) for parse logs in python but it's broken if Log Rotation on server. What decision can be used instead? tail -f in popen - it is not Pythonic way

Comment: Incidentally, you would need to use `tail -F`, not `tail -f` -- `-F` will notice file rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be that difficult to add log rotation functionality. For example, if you have:

```
for line in tailer.follow(open('test.txt')):
    print line
```

You could add a callback to a function that periodically checked for the existence of the next filename. If it exists, break out of the loop and begin one on the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Upon logrotate event next thing will happen:

1. log file's inode wasn't changed but log was renamed to new name (e.g. log.out.1)
2. logrotate creates new file with same name (log.out) (I'm not sure :-)

tailer module will still look at old file inode.

You have to monitor log file's inode value for correct log following.
This is what is 'tail -F' for.

As you can see in its source, tailer module hasn't been designed to following logrotation of source file: it based on recipe

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035/

and is unuseful for your task.

Please take a look at comments for source recipe.

--

P.S. or use my one, which is wrapper around 'tail -f' :)

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577398-tail-f-with-inode-monitor/